# How to link OnUDPRead Event

Tags: delphi, udp

I am unable to link the OnUDPRead Event to IdUDPServer.

Code is as follows:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, IdUDPServer, IdGlobal, IdSocketHandle, Classes;

var
  udp: TIdUDPServer;
  buffer: TIdBytes;
  myBinding: TIdSocketHandle;

procedure UDPRead (Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
  var
    bytes_received: integer;
  begin
    bytes_received:= AData.size;
  end;

begin
  myBinding := udp.Bindings.Add;
  myBinding.IP := '0.0.0.0';
  myBinding.Port := 5100;

  udp.OnUDPRead := UDPRead; // Error occurs here
  udp.Active := True;
end.
```

I received the error message:

```
 [dcc32 Error] ACUR401_20170802_UDPServer.dpr(16): E2029 ';' expected but 'OF' found
 [dcc32 Error] ACUR401_20170802_UDPServer.dpr(28): E2009 Incompatible types: 'method pointer and regular procedure'
```

I believe my difficulty is that I am unable to link the eventhandler to the procedure.

Comment: It must be an object method. What you have is regular procedure.

Comment: The errors you report don't match the code you provide. Details matter. Looks like you attempted to add `of object` to the end of your procedure declaration, at least in some other version of your code. If you don't want to instantiate an instance of a class, just use a class method.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a matching object method to the [**OnUDPRead**](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdUDPServer_OnUDPRead.html) property. What you've assigned is a regular procedure. Do something like this:

```
type
  TMyObject = class
  public
    procedure UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; AData: TIdBytes;
      ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
  end;

{ TMyObject }

procedure TMyObject.UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; AData: TIdBytes;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  Received: Integer;
begin
  Received := Length(AData);
  ...
end;

var
  MyObject: TMyObject;
  MyServer: TIdUDPServer;
  MyBinding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  MyServer := TIdUDPServer.Create(nil);
  try
    MyBinding := MyServer.Bindings.Add;
    MyBinding.IP := '0.0.0.0';
    MyBinding.Port := 5100;

    MyObject := TMyObject.Create;
    try
      MyServer.OnUDPRead := MyObject.UDPRead;
      MyServer.Active := True;
    finally
      MyObject.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MyServer.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: But better move the server object inside that helper object.

Comment: I have tried your code. And now i get the error "Parameter lists differ". I believe that means the parameters in the Procedure are different than the "structure" of the OnUDPRead. I have looked at http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TUDPReadEvent.html

Comment: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/11/215650.html I seem to have find a person with a similar problem, but i am not skilled enough to understand fully what the solution is.

Comment: If the parameter lists differ, make them the same. The error message is clear enough. How hard have you tried to understand any of this?

Comment: But I did. And it still came up with the same error. The Code from Victoria already has the same parameters. But it still gave the error.

Comment: Clearly you didn't. The compiler doesn't get this wrong. The parameters don't match. Do you understand what the error message means?

Comment: The parameter list should look like this: (AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle) Note the *const* for the AData parameter.

Comment: Thanks. The const helped. Out of curiousity, am i looking at the wrong page? This was the page I was following: http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TUDPReadEvent.html

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your comments are hostile and condescendent, especially towards a beginner. The actual parameter list changed and the one posted by Victoria isn't valid anymore. Dave Nottage pointed the actual change.

Comment: @altai I know. But it's not our place to do the job for the asker. A basic prerequisite is to read error messages. Asker did not. I was trying to provoke the asker to get over the classic beginner's weakness of not attempting to read and understand error messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not sure that's the best approach, but thanks anyway for taking the criticism. I maintain a Delphi codebase and these library changes render code maintenance very frustrating IMO. No wonder why the community is dying, people are definitely moving away from it.